# PIC16F84A assembly program

Tags: digital-logic, pic

In PIC16F84A, numbers are represented as 8-bit binary sequences. Assume that you would to develop a language that represents both positive and negative numbers. So, your language should contain the following statements:

- `int i` to declare an integer in memory location i.
- `i = k` to store constant value `k` (positive or negative) in location `i`.
- `i + j` to perform addition.
- `i - j` to perfom subtraction.

  1. For each statement, show how you will implement in assembly code.
  2. What is the maximum and minimum values for `k`?

Any one check that please! i mini=-10. ,i max =+10.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you just put your homework here. Is there a question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions without demonstrated effort or explaining what has been attempted are not accepted.

Comment: This question lacks at least in two points: it is not about electrical engineering, and it does not show any effort. Vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would represent your numbers using 2's complement, which is what is built in to the microcontroller.  For an 8 bit 2's complement value, the range is -128 to 127.

The PIC 16F instruction set documentation provides all the information you need to write the assembler code (this smells like a homework problem with no work attempted so you get a partial answer).

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31029a.pdf

Comment: No doubt this is course work. The instructor is trying to be tricky by using the PIC16F84A controller as the architecture model. But then the instructor could have picked something really odd like the [FACOM 128B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FACOM_128).

Comment: @Dan1138 i think like that